# Name for radio group

Tags: angular

I'm trying to setup name for radio group elements. But it doesn't work. Here is my component:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: "page.html"
})
export class FieldComponent {

    @Input() control: Control;
    @Input() value: string;
    @Input() label: string;
}
```

Here is my template:

```
{{label}}
<input type="radio" name="{{label}}" [value]="true" [ngFormControl]="control" />
<input type="radio" [name]="label" [value]="true" [ngFormControl]="control" />
<input type="radio" name="abc" [value]="false" [ngFormControl]="control" />
```

`{{label}}` works ok. I did it only for test.

But why is that `name="{{label}}"` and `[name]="label"` not works. Only when I do hardcode name="abc" I can see the name in html.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="radio" [attr.name]="label" [value]="true" [ngFormControl]="control" />
```

You can use `[attr.attrName]` for attribute binding. You can get more info about Attribute directives [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html).